# Bezier curve gradient in html5/css3

Tags: html, css, gradient

Doesn't look like its possible to do a non-linear (e.g. Bezier-curve fill) css3 gradient; anyone know if it's possible in html5 canvas?

Comment: The only non-linear type of gradients in CSS3 is *radial*

Comment: Thanks, but was meaning non-linear & non-radial.

Comment: @stephenwil Well Zoltans comment pretty much nailed it. It is not possible (although: You can combine multiple backgrounds to achieve a non-linear gradient effect).

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies folks

Comment: I know it's been a while, but nowadays in addition to linear and radial there are also specs for [conic gradients](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#conic-gradients).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the initial comment is really about the rate of progression from one color to another within the gradient, not the physical shape of the gradient.

To address the former: no, unfortunately at this time there is no way to do non-linear CSS gradient fills. However, you can use successive color stops to achieve some level of control over the shape of your gradient.

You could mess with the little squares under the gradient in the [Colorzilla gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) or read the [MDN linear-gradient article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient#Gradient_with_multiple_color_stops) for detailed info on creating your own color stops.

The color stops can be used pretty creatively, especially combined with `background-size`. Here is a great [collection of CSS patterns](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) built using gradients.

CSS preprocessors can also be used to generate gradients that *feel* non-linear (although they simply generate lots of stops without you having to think about each one). A recent [CSS Tricks article about easing linear gradients](https://css-tricks.com/easing-linear-gradients/) demonstrates one such approach.